# cx_oracle SQL command not properly ended; attempting to compare excel file with database query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am attempting to do a verification check against an Excel file. This excel file contains columns with headers [X,Y,Z].

I am trying to run a SQL query that searches based off of column X in the excel file.

The column name in the table in the database is not the same as the column name in the excel file.

This query works fine in SQL alone, when I input the values of X for the missing values.

I set parameters to make sure that I will be able to run a query even if the number of records is greater than 1000. (no issues with this part)

r is the clause 'where X is in ('

I am using the following code using cx_oracle(simplified)

```
connection = cx.connect(.....)
CON= connection.cursor()

spry = ("Select table1.something, table2.something2 as X from table1,table2 where condition1 = some value {}")
```

I have tried several variations of this code, but to no avail.

```
sqry2 = sqry.format(where clause)
CON.execute(sqry2)
CON.fetchall()
```

When I run this in python, it errors out.

I end up with the error below.

Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Please let me know if you need any more details or any questions

Comment: Please provide the full query text (the value of sqry2). If it contains a semicolon (;) that needs to be removed!

Comment: Be very, very careful (i.e don't do it) when concatenating or interpolating text to create a SQL statement.  This can be a huge 'SQL injection' security risk.  Try to use bind variables, see the cx_Oracle documentation [Using Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).